# Running php artisan server with LAN host not working

Tags: php, laravel, server, laravel-artisan, artisan-serve

I'm trying to access my Laravel project APIs on my mobile phone. Since both my machine and mobile are under the same Wi-Fi, I'm trying to run the `php artisan serve` on my LAN like so.

```
php artisan serve --host=192.167.1.101
```

This runs fine and I do connect, but no API calls to the server go through. It doesn't even log a call.

This seems to work just fine when I use my mobile internet and hotspot my machine. But this is not convenient as my mobile internet is very limited.

I've boiled it down to be an issue with the LAN. But that's as far as my knowledge goes.

Is there anything I need to enable?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just run `php artisan serve` on "your machine" and connect to it via `http://192.167.1.101`?

Comment: @brombeer Keeps saying "Took too long to responsd".. also, I'd need to be able to access it on my mobile device. `php artisan serve` runs on `127.0.0.1:8000` by default

Comment: Having the same issue, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months, I've finally found the solution. Turns out my Firewall was set to not trust my WiFi network (which I use for my LAN).

As soon as I added it to the trusted list, everything works!